# Is Python by default installed on Windows?

Tags: windows, python

I have a Windows machine that cannot connect to the Internet, and I need to know if it should already have Python installed on it.

If so, it will save me the hassle of installing Python via a thumb drive. If you know where it is installed, that will also be helpful for me to know where. Plus I'm a Linux/Mac guy, so my Windows Command Prompt skills are limited.

Comment: No. Run Python takes you to the Store to instal lit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Python is not installed in Windows by default.

You will need to install Python from one of the various sources based on your own specific needs.